# iOS: How to retrieve jpg images from url (ipcam) and show them as video

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to create a type of ip cam viewer for iOS.
The idea is to retrieve a jpg image from an ipcam over a specific `Url` ongoing within a loop; the result will be a video of the ip cam.

I tried already with `NSURLConnection`, but run into the memory leak of `NSURLConnection`. I run the `NSURLCOnnection` in a different thread and it seems, that each retrieved image remains stored somewhere in the memory, leading to the situation that after some time the app crashes.

Is there any solution to force the `NSURLConnection` to not caching every retrireved image?
Or is there the possibility to assign a certain memory space to be reused for every retrieved image?
Or is there another possibility to retrieve a image from a `Url` and show it inside a `UIImageView` without memory leaks (perhaps a special framework)?

I would be glad for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do something like this whit an refresh time interval:

`[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(updateImage) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];`

and update the imageview with this method

```
- (void)updateImage {

if (!isDownloading) {
    isDownloading = YES;
   NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"imageUrl"]];
[request addValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",[NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"timestamp_preventCache"];
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue new] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
        isDownloading = NO;
        if( data ){

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
            });
        }
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello all I gave a try to NSUrlSession. The result install the same except I change configuration to background mode.
There is no more memory leak, but the single request are too slow, means that from the moment I start my request to the moment I get my jpg updated there is too much delay. When I change to configuration default or emphasis the delay is no more there, but again there is a memory leak filling up the memory.

I suspect the problem could be ARC, which does not clearing up dependencies properly.

Perhaps any one has a suggestion for me?